# Remove Escape Sequence Not Working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, regex, string

I have HTML code like this:

```
 <tr>
     <th colspan="2" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 11px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid white" align="left">
         Some Text Here                    
     </th>
 </tr>
```

I am storing this in string like this:

```
 string gtr = 
        @"<tr>
            <th colspan=""2"" style=""padding: 10px; font-size: 11px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid white"" align=""left"">
                 Some Text Here
            </th>
        </tr>";
```

But When I Debug It Show String Like this:

```
<tr>
     <th colspan=\"2\" style=\"padding: 10px; font-size: 11px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid white\" align=\"left\">
         Some Text Here
     </th>
</tr>
```

It Show Escape Sequence Characters.

It Tried to remove them like this

```
gtr = gtr.Replace(@"\","");
```

and **use all other possible methods**

But **this not working** it always show string **gtr** with Escape Sequence Character.

How to achieve string without Escape Sequence Character and gives only clear HTML code.

**I am only Using ASP.NET with C# and not Using MVC  and this is a static content.**

Comment: why do you want to remove escape sequence ?

Comment: The debugger sometings doesn't show the string as it will be realy viewed. Do you have other problem than the way this string is shown on the debugger?

Comment: Yes i want to remove escape sequence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But When I Debug It Show String Like this

That's because you're looking at the string *in the debugger*. The string doesn't actually contain those backslashes - they're just part of the debug output, which escapes various characters to make it look like it would as a regular string literal in code.

Write the string to a file or the console and you'll see the backslashes really aren't there.

As an alternative way of convincing yourself of this even in the debugger, try this:

```
 string x = "\"\"";
 int y = x.Length;
 char z = x[0];
```

Then in the debugger you'll see that `y` is 2, and `z` is just `"` - it may be escaped again, but clearly it can't be both characters in `\"` as it's just a `char`.

Comment: @user3049290: Well your problem *isn't* the backslashes. It may well be in terms of line breaks, or other whitespace - but it isn't the backslashes. It doesn't help that you haven't said anything in your post about "comparing this string to HTML" nor said what you mean by "its not working".

Comment: object= object.Replace(gtr, string.Empty); this not wokring if i use simple line **Some Text Here** than only its works

Comment: @user3049290: What is `object`, and what do you mean by "not working"? Basically you haven't given us nearly enough information to find the *real* problem, but I can assure you that it's *not* the backslashes, because they aren't in the string that `gtr` refers to. So drop that theory, and move on to look at where the strings really differ.

Comment: Yes I was doing mistake back slash are not problem

Comment: Object is my HTML page

Answer (score 2):

When I check you code in Text Visualizer from Quick Watch it show string without escape characters, See following snap

[image]

Comment: I too check like this